# Photo creds or photo cred?

Tags: word-choice, slang, abbreviations

A lot of people nowadays use the phrase "photo creds" eg:

> Here's an awesome photo of me! Photo creds to John!

Creds usually means credit or credits. But then you get the sentences:

> Photo credits to John
>
> Photo credit to John

Which of these is correct? If it's the latter, then it should be "photo cred to John" abbreiviated, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Cred](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cred)* is recognized as an informal slang abbreviation of *credibility*, not credit:

> noun,
>
> Slang.
>
> 1. the quality of being believable or worthy of respect, especially within a particular social, professional, or other group:
>
> *If you wear this t-shirt, you’ll be earning geek cred.*
>
> *Both chefs have plenty of Southern cred.*

According to the Urban Dictionary, *[creds](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cred)* is the informal slang for *credentials* or *credit*:

> Credentials earned in life by experience.
>
> Credit given.
>
> *He talked about being in prison like it gave him creds.*

*Photo **credit** to John*, is the idiomatic expression to give John credit for his creative initiative. The expression *[credits to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=credit%20to%2Ccredits%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccredit%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccredits%20to%3B%2Cc0)* is 7 times less common than *credit to* in searchable written media, and is predominantly used for financial credit transactions. All these expressions are linguistically related in their etymological root: *credo*:

> late 12c., from Latin, literally "*I believe*," first word of the
>   Apostles' and Nicene *Creeds*, first person singular present indicative
>   of *credere* "*to believe*,"
>
> perhaps from PIE compound **kerd-dhe*- "*to believe*," literally "*to put
>   one's heart*"
>
> (cognates: Old Irish *cretim*, Irish *creidim*, Welsh *credu* "*I believe*,"
>   Sanskrit *śrad-dhā*- "faith"). The nativized form is *creed*.
>
> General sense of "*formula or statement of belief*" is from 1580s.

The cutting edge of word evolution is a double-edged sword: you can make words mean anything you want, but then you never can be sure exactly what they mean.

Comment: So I guess "creds" is used to mean credit then...

Comment: Seems that way, but creds hasn't made it to the prestigious Oxforddictionaries.com :-)

Answer (score -1):

It's best not to use "cred"/"creds" instead of "credit". "Credit" is a short word - you won't die if you type it out in full!